# Can you merge graphic text with a transparent background over a video loop on raspberry pi and output to HDMI?

Tags: video, video-input

Is there a way to use a Raspberry Pi to play a video loop from an SD card in folder1, and then using a chroma key, remove the green screen in the background of a graphic text in folder2 (Or perhaps create the graphic text using a transparent PNG file) to then overlay the graphic text, with a now transparent background, over the video file, and output the merged elements to the HDMI port of the Raspberry Pi as a continuous loop?

Comment: Hey there, welcome! Sounds like you're after some kind of digital signage solution. Have you look into professional solutions for such? There are open source, free, and paid solutions that provide this kind of functionality if you're not in a position to be able to write your own code for it.